# Invariant complement to a $G$-module (not necessarily a vector space)

Tags: modules, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, $R$ a ring (not necessarily a field), and $M$ an $R$-module. Assume we have a group action $\rho:G \times M \to M$.

If there exists a $G$-invariant submodule $N \subseteq M$, is it always true that there exists a $G$-invariant complement $N'$ to $N$ such that we have a direct sum decomposition of $M$ as
$$M=N \oplus N'$$

The proposition is when $R$ is a field. I can't figure out however where the assumption that $R$ is a field is necessary for the proof. Is the theorem true for general modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true at all.  In fact, there need not exist *any* submodule ($G$-invariant or not) $N'\subset M$ such that $M=N\oplus N'$.  Take, for instance, $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=2\mathbb{Z}$.  You can make this example equivariant for any group $G$ by just letting $G$ act trivially.

(By the way, it also isn't true in general when $R$ is a field.  For instance, if $R$ is any field, $G=\mathbb{Z}$, and $G$ acts on $M=R^2$ by $1\cdot(u,v)=(u,u+v)$, then the subspace $N=\{(0,x):x\in R)\}$ is $G$-invariant but has no $G$-invariant complement.  The case when it is true is if $G$ is a finite group and $R$ is a field whose characteristic does not divide $|G|$.)

Comment: What about a finite group acting on a module? Or perhaps a group acting on a free module $R^n$ where $R$ is a ring whose characteristic doesn't divide the order of the group. I'm trying to understand where exactly the assumption that $R$ is a field is necessary (at least in the finite group case).

Comment: The typical way the proof goes when $R$ is a field (and the characteristic does not divide $|G|$) is that you first choose an $R$-linear splitting $M\to N$ of the inclusion $N\to M$ and then average its conjugates by elements of $G$ to get a $G$-invariant splitting.  You need $R$ to be a field (or at least a semisimple ring) to get your initial splitting in the first step.

Comment: In any case, if you want this to hold in general for some $R$ and $G$, you must at least have that any submodule of an $R$-module has a complement, since you always can let $G$ act trivially.  This is not true of most rings (the rings it is true of are called semisimple).